# Is there way to trigger events when a custom emoji is used in Slack API?

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I'm looking to build a slack app and I like to find a trigger that listens to a custom emoji. for example, when I mention coffee emoji

"here's my treat ☕️ @jon_doe"

it fires event and do something in the backend

looks like there's `app_mention` event that fires when @bot is mentioned, but I like my custom emoji `:custom_coffee` to be tracked.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a specific event type that fires when someone uses a custom emoji. The [reaction_added](https://api.slack.com/events/reaction_added) event type would send an event payload to your app whenever a user reacts to a message with an emoji. You would then have to filter for the custom emoji of your choice. You could also have your app subscribe to the [message event type](https://api.slack.com/events/message). This event type would fire whenever someone sends a message in a channel your bot is in. You would then have to include logic that looks for the specific custom emoji.

Comment: thank you. I see. tracking every message in channel to find custom emoji would be very expensive as there are many people communicate. thanks for the tip!